# Does adding indexing to automatically created tables reduce performance?

Tags: mongodb

Does creating this index ,every time we insert data to the collection, reduce performance.
Is there any better way to do it?

```js
db.collection.createIndex( { "x": 1 }, { unique: true } )
db.collection.insertOne(data);
```

I want the table to be created if it doesn't exist and also have a unique key constraint to the table.

Comment: Reduce performance as opposed to what?

Comment: Does this reduce performance ,as we are creating an index every time we add data to the table